# How to render react component from a json object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a menu component that accepts a json object with all menu itens.
For icons i use `react-icons/io`.
The json object is something like this:

```
const menus = {
    Item1: { buttonText: 'Item 1 text', icon: { IoLogoAndroid }, path: 'item 1 path' },
    Item2: { buttonText: 'Item 2 text', icon: { IoLogoAndroid }, path: 'item 2 path'},
};
```

This is the Menu function that will render the menu items as buttons:

```
const buttons = Object.keys(this.props.menus).map((menu) => {
        return (
            <a key={menu} href={this.props.menus[menu].path}
                onClick={this.changeMenu.bind(this, menu)}>
                {...this.props.menus[menu].icon} <- fail here
                {this.props.menus[menu].buttonText}
            </a>
        );
    })
```

I tried many ways to render the icon, but i am clueless on how this could work. Not sure if this is even possible. Any pointers?

Comment: I would like to know why this question gets 2 downvotes. Doesn't 3 people offer they help, providing 3 solutions to the problem in 1 day, is not enough to qualified as a valid question? If you are one of who downvote can you clarify so i don't make the same mistake again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing the icon from where you are defining the object then just tag it `<IoLogoAndroid/>;`, so react knows it should treat it as an element to render.

```
const menus = {
    Item1: { buttonText: 'Item 1 text', icon: <IoLogoAndroid/> , path: 'item 1 path' },
    Item2: { buttonText: 'Item 2 text', icon: <IoLogoAndroid/>, path: 'item 2 path'},
};
```

And then just call it directly (remove the `...`)

```
<a key={menu} href={this.props.menus[menu].path}
    onClick={this.changeMenu.bind(this, menu)}>
    {this.props.menus[menu].icon}
    {this.props.menus[menu].buttonText}
</a>
```

Alternatively you could just call `React.createElement` if you don't want to tag it in your object definition.

```
<a key={menu} href={this.props.menus[menu].path}
    onClick={this.changeMenu.bind(this, menu)}>
    {React.createElement(this.props.menus[menu].icon)}
    {this.props.menus[menu].buttonText}
</a>
```

Here is a sample showing the 2 implementations https://codesandbox.io/s/pmvyyo33o0

Comment: Yes this is also a possible solution, however no reason to access the array once again, since each item, is already being `mapped`

Comment: I tried that. it breaks with: 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {IoLogoAndroid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'. The second way gives the error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't adapt the definition of the menus object. The icons shouldn't be a object, it should be `icon: IoLogoAndroid` or `icon: <IoLogoAndroid/>` remove the `{...}` from the icon value. I edited my answer.

Comment: it work. Passing in json as tag works. But calling React.createElement still gives the same error. I may doing something wrong, it is my first react project. Anyway you solved. Tks

Answer (score 2):

I was just working with a similar project, and I managed to make it work, with a syntax like this

I here have an array of objects (like yours)

```
links: [
      {
      name: 'Frontend',  
      link: 'https://github.com/Thomas-Rosenkrans-Vestergaard/ca-3-web', 
      icon: <FaCode size={40} />,
      id: 1
      }, 
      {
      name: 'Backend',
      link: 'https://github.com/Thomas-Rosenkrans-Vestergaard/ca-3-backend',
      icon: <FaCogs size={40}/>,
      id: 2
      },
      {
      name: 'Mobile',
      link: 'https://github.com/Thomas-Rosenkrans-Vestergaard/ca-3-app',
      icon: <FaMobile size={40} />,
      id: 3
       }]
```

I then render my component by mapping, where I pass in the entire object as a prop

```
const projects = this.state.projects.map((project, i) => {
  return(
 <Project key={`Project key: ${i}`} project={project}  />
  )
})
```

I then use objectdestructing to get the prop

```
 const { logo } = this.props.project
```

then it can just be displayed

```
//in my case I use antd framework, so I pass the FAIcon component in as a prop 

 <Meta
    avatar={logo}
    title={title}
    description={description}
  />
```

I suppose you could do the same thing, by just passing the entire menu object in as a prop, and then accessing the icon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following:

```
icon: <IoLogoAndroid />
```

And in the code (remove the spread operator):

```
this.props.menus[menu].icon
```

Also, a few refactoring suggestions.

- Do you really need to have an object of objects? Why not an array of objects, where every item has a "name" prop? It will be easier to iterate through, as you can access props directly from map, unlike with object keys.
- You are creating a button list, so you should have ul and li tags aswell.
- Consider passing only a reference to onClick such as:

  ```
  onClick={this.changeMenu}
  ```

If you need to pass data around, you should use dataset for that. Pass a name/path then find it inside the change handler to avoid rebinding inside every re-render.

**Refactored suggestion with an array of objects**

```
changeMenu = e => {
    const { menus } = this.props;
    const { menuName } = e.target.dataset;
    const menu = menus.find(menu => menu.name === menuName);
    // Do something with menu
    return;
  };

  renderMenu() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.menus.map(menu => (
          <li key={menu.name} style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
            <a
              data-menu-name={menu.name}
              href={menu.path}
              onClick={this.changeMenu}
            >
              {menu.icon}
              {menu.buttonText}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {createElement} from "react";
import IconDocumentText from "@/components/icons/IconDocumentText";

const SomeBlock = () => {
    const icons = {
        input: IconDocumentText,
    }

    return(
        <>
            {createElement(icons.input, {className:'w-4 h-4'})}
        </>
    }

}

export default SomeBlock;


---

IconDocumentText:

export default function IconDocumentText({className="w-6 h-6"}) {
    return (
        <svg className={className} ...></svg>
    )
}
```